# Plotting a 3D graph of `sqrt(1+1/(kr)^2)`

Tags: matlab, math, plot

I am trying to plot the following equation in MATLAB:

`ratio = sqrt(1+1/(kr)^2)`

With k and r on the x and y axes, and ratio on the z axis. I used meshgrid to create a matrix with values for x and y varying from 1 to 10:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid([1:1:10],[1:1:10]);
```

The problem now is to create values for z. I've tried to just type the whole equation in, but that gives this result:

```
>> Z = sqrt(1+1/(x .* y)^2)??? 
Error using ==> mldivide
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

So what I did is go to through the whole process manually, which produces the right graph in the end:

```
z = z^2;
z = 1 ./ z;
z = 1 + z;
z = sqrt(z);
mesh(x,y,z)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Or a way to type in the equation and let MATLAB handle the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Z = sqrt(1+1./(x .* y).^2);
 surf(Z);
```

The problem that you had is related to using `/` instead of `./` and `^2` instead of `.^2`

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I didn't think of doing all the operations component wise...

Comment: I will accept, it's just Stackexchange won't let me accept till 11 minutes or so has passed...